# Android: How to search data using SugarORM

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sugarorm

I am not familiar with Sqlite and therefore is using SugarORM, a database library, with its documentation at http://satyan.github.io/sugar/creation.html

Most of its function is same as that in sqlite, but using simplier commands.

### ExerciseDB

```
public class ExerciseDB extends SugarRecord 
{
    @Column(name = "ex_recordId", unique = true, notNull = true)
    private String ex_recordId;
    private String ex_group;
    private String ex_name;    
    private int ex_cal;

    public ExerciseDB()
    {
    }

    public ExerciseDB(String ex_recordId, String ex_group, String ex_name, int ex_cal) 
    {
        this.ex_recordId = ex_recordId;
        this.ex_group = ex_group;
        this.ex_name = ex_name;
        this.ex_cal = ex_cal;
    }
```

### Database is saved as follows for example:

```
ExerciseDB e0001= new ExerciseDB("ex0001", "Sports", "AAA", 190); save(e0001);
ExerciseDB e0002= new ExerciseDB("ex0002", "Sports", "BBB", 190); save(e0002);
```

### Question:

I would like to ask how could I search for the record "ex0001"?
I have tried to search using the following code:

```
ExerciseDB.find(ExerciseDB.class, key);
List<ExerciseDB> books = ExerciseDB.find(ExerciseDB.class, "ex_recordId = ?", key, null,null,null);
String gg = books.get(1).get_ex_group();
```

but it reports

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: ex0001 (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM Ex_Records WHERE ex0001
```

### Official Documentation for find:

```
List<Book> books = Book.find(Book.class, "author = ?", new String{author.getId()});
```

and

```
Book book = Book.findById(Books.class, 1);
Author author = book.author;
```

but does not know what this `1` stand for and how to find

### Code Documentation is as follows:

```
    public static <T> List<T> find(Class<T> type, String whereClause, String... whereArgs) {
        return find(type, whereClause, whereArgs, null, null, null);
    }

public static <T> List<T> find(Class<T> type, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs, String groupBy, String orderBy, String limit) {
        SugarDb db = getSugarContext().getSugarDb();
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = db.getDB();
        T entity;
        List<T> toRet = new ArrayList<T>();
        Cursor c = sqLiteDatabase.query(NamingHelper.toSQLName(type), null, whereClause, whereArgs,
                groupBy, null, orderBy, limit);
        try {
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                entity = type.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
                SugarRecord.inflate(c, entity);
                toRet.add(entity);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            c.close();
        }
        return toRet;
    }
```

The basics should be similar to Sqlite...would there be anyone who can offer help based on the above code documentation? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: why do you use such a strange api? use greenDAO for example, its much more simple and easier in use...

Comment: i at first also try using greenDAO but it seems the structure is rather complicated.. and after seeing SugarORM...it seems extremely easy and user friendly as all in all my database is just several columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use its another method `findWithQuery` as follows:

```
List<ExerciseDB> bb = ExerciseDB.findWithQuery(ExerciseDB.class, "Select * from Ex_Records where ex_recordId = ?", "ex0001");
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have found the answer by now, but for those who came across this question and wants to know.

Sugar formats the column names: "read" becomes "READ", and isRead becomes "IS_READ". So you can use your SugarRecord.find(). You just need to figure out how does sugar formats your column name "ex_recordId". I think it will format it to either EX_RECORD_ID or EXRECORD_ID.